how in Process Edit
 var Currency =request.CurrencyType.Select(x=> new Sepehr.Domain.Banks.BankAccountCurrencyType
 {
     Id=x.Id,
     Title=x.Title,
     CreateDateTime=x.Id != 0 ? _context.BankAccountCurrencies.Where(a => a.Id == x.Id).Select(x=>x.CreateDateTime).FirstOrDefault() : DateTime.Now,
     CreatedBy=x.Id != 0 ? _context.BankAccountCurrencies.Where(a => a.Id == x.Id).Select(x => x.CreatedBy).FirstOrDefault()  :  request.Actor.UserName,
     CreatedIp=x.Id != 0 ? _context.BankAccountCurrencies.Where(a => a.Id == x.Id).Select(x => x.CreatedIp).FirstOrDefault() : request.Actor.Ip,
     ModifiedDateTime=x.Id != 0 ? DateTime.Now :null
 });
 _context.BankAccountCurrencies.UpdateRange(Currency);
if( _context.SaveChanges()>0) 
     return true;
return false;

hi Friends . In this method, add and edit operations are performed together.
The problem I have is how to set the createdDateTime, CreatedBy and CreatedIp values ​​when editing
In this method, FirstOrDefault is used, and if I use the same method, it causes repetition and it causes a drop in performance.

Start the query from _context.BankAccountCurrencies instead. You don't even need to call UpdateRange, the DbContext already tracks the currencies it loaded and will detect the changes

.... what is this code trying to do ? This can't add rows because the BankAccountCurrencyType.Id value is already set to a non-default value. Update or UpdateRange act as an UPSERT only if the Id is database generated and the ID of new items keeps its default value

Is one of those lists short and could be read into local variable? That way you would need to get a list just once and iterate it over another list. Less read operations to DB.
This works best if BankAccountCurriencies list is short or CurrencyType list is short. Iterating short list over longer list consumes little memory and saves DB operations.

It seems the real issue is how to INSERT or UPDATE objects, while retaining the Created... values in existing objects. In other words, the Created... properties should be ignored on UPDATE.
Both Update and UpdateRange will INSERT any object whose primary key properties have the default values and UPDATE any object whose keys are non-default. The following code would upsert all items without querying the database:
request.CurrencyType.Select(x=> new Sepehr.Domain.Banks.BankAccountCurrencyType
 {
     Id=x.Id,
     Title=x.Title,
     CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now,
     CreatedBy=request.Actor.UserName,
     CreatedIp=request.Actor.Ip,
     ModifiedDateTime=x.Id != 0 ? DateTime.Now :null
 });
 _context.BankAccountCurrencies.UpdateRange(Currency);
 _context.SaveChanges();

You can instruct EF Core to only update some properties on INSERT with SetAfterSaveBehavior :
modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccountCurrencyType>(entity =>
{                
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
          .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
    entity.Property(e => e.CreateDateTime)
          .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
          .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
});


This is exactly what I want. thanks
